# Introspection in Ruby

Tags: ruby, reflection, introspection

I manipulate an array of symbols, where some of them are potentially Ruby class names (e.g :Fixnum).

How can I select them ?

Of course, I don't know in advance the complete list of these symbols...
Of course I do that in Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the check with const_get if you check whether the const is defined first:

```
[:Integer, :Dog, :Fixnum, :String, :Rat].select{ |x| Object.const_defined?(x) && Object.const_get(x).class === Class }
=> [:Integer, :Fixnum, :String]
```

Answer (score 2):

I hate to use `eval` but....

```
[:Integer, :Dog, :Fixnum, :String, :Rat].select{|x| defined? x.to_s && Class === eval(x.to_s)}
```

I tried `Kernel.const_get` but could not get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).map(&:name).map(&:to_sym) & [:Integer, :Dog, :Fixnum, :String, :Rat]
=> [:Fixnum, :Integer, :String]
```